# Converting string to int using C#

Tags: c#

I am using C# and I want to convert a string to int to verify name. For example `**` or `12` is not a name. I just want to convert the string into ASCII values and then will verify the name. How do I do that?

Comment: SO needs to reject any question that contains the string "wanna"

Comment: +1 @Michael. I still have no clue what the real question is, just gave a stab at it based on the title itself.

Comment: I fear you are doing things too complicated. To verify a name doesn't contain numbers you could just use the string.contains() method for example

Comment: Another +1 from me. I had a stab based on the content of the message instead. :)

Comment: +1 from me, the question is legit, the title is misleading.

Answer (score 4):

Converting back and forth is simple:

```
int i = int.Parse("42");
string s = i.ToString();
```

If you do not know that the input string is valid, use the `int.TryParse()` method.

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand, you want to verify that a given string represents a valid name? I'd say you should probably provide more details as to what constitutes a valid name to you, but I can take a stab at it. You could always iterate over all the characters in the string, making sure they're letters or white space:

```
public bool IsValidName(string theString)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < theString.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        if (!char.IsLetter(theString[i]) && !char.IsWhiteSpace(theString[i]))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Of course names can have other legitimate characters, such as apostrophe ' so you'd have to customize this a bit, but it's a starting point from what I understand your question truly is. (Evidently, not all white space characters would qualify as acceptable either.)

Comment: +1 for the name check, although I'd personally use a regex for it.

Answer (score 0):

There multiple ways to convert:

```
try
{
    string num = "100";
    int value;
    bool isSuccess = int.TryParse(num, out value);
    if(isSuccess)
    {
        value = value + 1;
        Console.WriteLine("Value is " + value);
    }
}
catch (FormatException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It's not clear to me what you're trying to do, but you can get the ASCII codes for a string with this code:

```
System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str)
```