# how to convert an int into string in wpf?

Tags: c#, mysql

Im writing  C# program connecting with mysql. In my sql i have two tables one called car and other one called model .In my car table i have a column named modele_vehiclue with datatype int and also it is  a foreign key.Second table called model which is made of two columns modele_vehiclue datatype int and model_name varchar 
the problem starts when i run my program and enter data in my boxes it says you can convert a int to var char values .This is the code I'm using in my c# .
if you could help me with it you are making my day .

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@modele ", modele_vehiclue.Text));
```

Comment: tnx nico for taking ur time to answer my question .i saw this post but this is not what im looking for

Comment: Its exactly what your looking for. Make sure you read the whole set of answers and not just look at the highest rated one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115678/converting-string-to-int-using-c-sharp#answer-3115685 (further down) shows that you can use `int.Parse(string)` and if your not sure if the result will be a valid int then use `int.TryParse(string)`

Comment: nop bro haha tell me how this is exactly samething

Comment: `cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@modele ", int.Parse(modele_vehiclue.Text)));`

Comment: it says "input string was not in a correct format"

Comment: use `int.TryParse()` to validate the input first.https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Did not work Sir

Comment: anyway bro i will figure something out .Thank you for your advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `Parameters.Add` is more suitable in this case to specify the DataType of the value. for that you can use the [SqlDbType Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqldbtype(v=vs.110).aspx), and you can use `int.Parse()` or `int.TryParse()` for parsing as well. So You can try something like this:

```
int modele = 0;
if(int.TryParse(modele_vehiclue.Text, out modele)
{
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@modele", SqlDbType.Int).Value = modele;
}
else
{
    // display message that invalid input
}
```

Comment: i tired this bro it says "input string was not in a correct format"

Comment: So the issue is with the input that you are giving, which is not a valid integer and that's why `int.parse` failed to convert them. You can trust `int.TryParse` in this case. see the updated answer

Comment: thank you man .last questions what if i want do the same process other way around like convert int to string

Comment: @afgboy: just use `.ToString()` to convert an integer to a string

Comment: int modele = 0;
if(,ToString(modele_vehiclue.Text, out modele)
{
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@modele", SqlDbType.Int).Value = modele;
}
else
{
    // display message that invalid input
}

Comment: like that ? sorry im new in c # i do not a lot of stuff

Comment: No need for such complications, thats a simple thing `cmd.Parameters.Add("@someStr", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = modele.ToString();` No need for parsing

Comment: but where u place the text box?

Comment: The `Text` property of the TextBox control is a string there is no need to convert them again to a string, you can use `modele_vehiclue.Text` as the same

Comment: i put this 
cmd.Parameters.Add("@model", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = (modele_vehiclue.ToString());
procedure of function "Enter car " expects parameter '@modele which not supplied.

Comment: i got this message

Answer (score 0):

In the interst to answer this correctly.

**Converting a string to an int**

This is done really easily with one of the various built in methods such as.

[`int.Parse(string s)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h1hf19(v=vs.110).aspx) : This will attempt to convert the value passed as `s` to an `int` (`Int32`).  If the input string `s` is not a valid int the exception `FormatException` will be thrown

There are multiple overrides as listed here [`int.Parse Method`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.parse(v=vs.110).aspx)

Now the key here the **string must be a valid int representation** anything else will throw the `FormatException`

So this can be used as

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@modele ", int.Parse(modele_vehiclue.Text)));
```

**How to safely validate the string**

Now as we have just stated the string **must** be a valid int representation for this to succeed. Now if you are not 100% sure that the value of `modele_vehiclue.Text` property is a valid string representation of an int then you should validate it first.

Luckily this is really easy. There is a built in method called [`int.TryParse(string s, out int result`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx) method which returns a `Boolean` result (not an int).

So this could be used as.

```
int modele = 0;
//int.TryParse returns a true\false on operation success. The value of modele will be the converted int or zero if the operation failed.
if(int.TryParse(modele_vehiclue.Text, out modele) == true)
{
     //conversion success
     cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@modele ", modele);
}
else
{
     //handle failed conversion
     throw new Exception("modele_vehiclue.Text must be an int");
}
```

Comment: It is not necessary to check with ` == true` since `int.TryParse` returning a boolean

Comment: @un-lucky i understand that but given the comments on the post figured best to include that.

Comment: @Nico thank you man .last questions what if i want do the same process other way around like convert int to string

Comment: so just need to replace int.TryParse in the if with ToString >

Comment: Converting an int to string is very easy `int.ToString()`. say `int modele = 0`. Then you call `string y = modele.ToString()`