# how to add a class<int>instance，add to Class<string>instance

Tags: c#, oop

```
interface IA<T>
{T Value;}

Class A<T> : IA
{
  T Value;
  public A<T> saveClassA;
}

var A1= new A(123);
var A2 = new A("hihi");
A1.saveClassA = A2;
```

ERROR:Unable to cast object of type 'Developer.Test.DProperties`1[System.String]' to type 'Developer.Test.DProperties`1[System.Int32]'.

I need to store A2 in A1. So in future A1 changed, A2 can be notified.
I got a mismatch error.
How to do this.....

Comment: Class<int>, cast to Class<string>? do you know how to cast the class? the problem is class<T> and <T>can be anything, <string><bool><>.....

Comment: Even I changed (public A<T> saveClassA) to (public object saveClassA), I cannot Add (object)A2 to A1.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting string to int using C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115678/converting-string-to-int-using-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may define your classes in the following way:

```
Class B<T> : IA<T>
{
  T Value;
}

Class A<T1, T2> : IA<T1>
{
  T1 Value;
  public B<T2> saveClassA;
}

var A1= new A<int, string>(123);
var B2 = new B<string>("hihi");
A1.saveClassA = B2;
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try!